# Are there topological manifolds with boundary that are not compact?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

Following this question [Are there compact manifolds without boundary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278848/are-there-compact-manifolds-without-boundary)

I'm asking if there is any example of a manifold with boundary that is not compact, Is the interval $X=[0,1)$ a counterexample ? I mean $X$ is a $1-$dimensional manifold with boundary $\partial X=\{0\}$ but $X$ is not compact because $X$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$. Is this correct and are there any other examples ?

Comment: Think of $[0,1)$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen you are citing the same example I'm giving in my question.

Comment: Yes, think of this example. If you want to see more, remove a collection of disjoint open disks from the plane.